# Send Two LINQ Queries using One Model to View

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to display data on a graph for these two queries. I can display the data on a bar chart, one at a time. But I want to display them on the same page together.

```
public ActionResult Daily(string label)
{
    var DataContext = new BalanceDataContext();

    var month = label.Split('-')[0];
    var year = label.Split('-')[1];

    //Percentage of Estimated Electric Bills 
    var rdcd = new string[] { "CE", "IE" };
    var totalEstimated = (from a in DataContext.pujhaccds
                           join b in DataContext.pujhmtrds
                           on a.billnumber equals b.billnumber
                           where year.Equals(a.billdate.Value.Year)
                           && month.Equals(a.billdate.Value.Month)
                           && rdcd.Contains(b.reading_code)
                           group a by new {a.billdate.Value.Day} into p
                           orderby p.Key.Day ascending
                           select new Date1() { theDay2 = p.Key.Day, theCount2 = p.Count() });


    var totalday = (from m in DataContext.pujhaccds
                      where month.Equals(m.billdate.Value.Month) &&
                      year.Equals(m.billdate.Value.Year)
                      group m by new { m.billdate.Value.Day } into p
                      orderby p.Key.Day ascending
                      select new Date1() { theDay = p.Key.Day, theCount = p.Count() });

    int monthInt = 0;
    Int32.TryParse(month, out monthInt);
    string strMonthName = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(monthInt);
    ViewBag.Message = "Bills for: " + strMonthName + year;

    return View(new QueryView { Date2 = totalEstimated, Date1 = totalday.ToArray() });
}
```

Here is what the model looks like:

```
public class Date1
{   
public string Month { get; set; }
public string Year { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? DateStart { get; set; }
public DateTime? DateEnd { get; set; }
public int theDay { get; set; }
public int theDay2 { get; set; }
public string theString { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MMMM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? theDate { get; set; }
public int theCount { get; set; }
public int theCount2 { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to create another model to hold the data, but it doesn't seem to work

```
public class QueryView
{
    public IEnumerable<Date1> Date1 { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Date1> Date2 { get; set; }
}
```

I have this at the top of  my view, no error message:

```
@model CWebPortal.Models.QueryView
```

When I had this, I got errors:

```
@model IEnumerable<CWebPortal.Models.QueryView>
```

This works, but only for one Query from the controller:

```
@model IEnumerable<CWebPortal.Models.Date1>
```

This is how I'm grabbing the data for the graphs in the view:

```
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
        var items = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
        var ticks = [];
        var s1 = [];
        var s2 = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            ticks.push(items[i].theDay);
            s1.push(items[i].theCount);
        }
```

How do I get both queries into my view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach with combining them into new View Model is absolutely correct.

```
public class QueryView
{
    public IEnumerable<Date1> Date1 { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Date1> Date2 { get; set; }
}
```

and `@model CWebPortal.Models.QueryView` in your view.

Just make sure you access correct one in your javascript code:

```
  jQuery(function ($) {
    $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
    var viewModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)); // <--- updated
    var items = viewModel.Date1;  // <--- updated
    var ticks = [];
    var s1 = [];
    var s2 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        ticks.push(items[i].theDay);
        s1.push(items[i].theCount);
    }
```